# Proof by induction that $3^{4n + 1} + 5^{2n + 1}$ is divisble by $8$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

This is a homework problem:

> Prove that: $$ 3^{4n+1} + 5^{2n+1}$$ is divisible by $8$ for every natural number $n$.

Base case: $$n = 0$$

$$ 3^{0 + 1} + 5^{0 + 1} = 8$$
$$8\bmod8 = 0 $$ Base case verified.

Inductive Hypothesis: Assume for some $n$, $$ 3^{4n+1} + 5^{2n+1} =8k$$ where $k$ is any non-negative integer.

Prove that: $$ 3^{4(n+1)+1} + 5^{2(n+1)+1} =8l$$

Indeed: $$ 3^{4n+4+1} + 5^{2n+2+1} = 3^4\cdot3^{4n+1} + 5^2\cdot5^{2n+1}$$
$$ = 81\cdot3^{4n+1} + 25\cdot5^{2n+1} $$
$$ = (80+1)\cdot3^{4n+1} + (24+1)\cdot5^{2n+1} $$
$$ = 80\cdot3^{4n+1} + 24\cdot5^{2n+1} + 3^{4n+1} + 5^{2n+1} $$
$$ = 8(10\cdot3^{4n+1} + 3\cdot5^{2n+1}) + 8k $$
$$ = 8(10\cdot3^{4n+1} + 3\cdot5^{2n+1} + k) $$

Is this wrong in any particular way? My answer is different from the textbook, but I feel like I sufficiently proved that $ 3^{4(n+1)+1} + 5^{2(n+1)+1} =8l$.

Edit: What the book did:

$$ = 81\cdot3^{4n+1} + 25\cdot5^{2n+1} $$
$$ = (56+25)\cdot3^{4n+1} + 25\cdot5^{2n+1} $$
$$ = 56\cdot3^{4n+1}+25\cdot3^{4n+1} + 25\cdot5^{2n+1} $$
$$ = 56\cdot3^{4n+1}+25(3^{4n+1} + 5^{2n+1}) $$
$$ = 56\cdot3^{4n+1}+25(8k) $$
$$ = 8(7\cdot3^{4n+1}+25k) $$

Comment: This looks fine.  What did the book do?

Comment: The only thing that could be done easier is that you can just 'erase' the $80 \cdot 3^{4n+1}+24\cdot 5^{2n+1}$, because you are working $\mod 8$. Then, the induction hypothesis remains.

Comment: The book chose a different way of factoring (i.e. using the distributive law), the two proofs are both valid.

Comment: @mathematician I edited the question to add what the book did.

Comment: @Ragnar Do you mean, like I could have just skipped writing that step?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but you have a small typo $8 \times 4 = 32$, you want $8 \times 3 = 24$.

Comment: @Chase, yes, you could have skipped it, but you wouldn't have ended with something like $8(...)$. It's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods differ only in how they rearrange the summands to show dvisibility by $8$

$$\begin{eqnarray} 81a+25b &=&\,80a+24b+\color{#c00}{a+b} &=&\, (10a+3b+\color{#c00}k)\,\color{#c00}8\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{a+b = 8k} \\ 81a+25b &=&\, 56a + 25(\color{#c00}{a+b}) &=&\, (7a+25\color{#c00}k)\,\color{#c00}8\\
 \end{eqnarray}$$

More simply: $\ {\rm mod}\ 8\!:\ 81\equiv 1\equiv 25\ \Rightarrow\ 81a + 25b\equiv \color{#c00}{a+b \equiv 0}$

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks fine.  Another method that is slightly cleaner: Let $S_n=3^{4n+1}+5^{2n+1}=3\cdot 81^n+5\cdot25^n$.  Note that $S_n$ satisfies $$ S_n=106S_{n-1}-2025S_{n-2} $$
(This can be found by that fact that $u_n:=c_1A^n+c_2B^n$ satisfies the recursion $u_n=(A+B)u_{n-1}-ABu_{n-2}$)

This recursion implies that if $k|S_{n}$ and $k|S_{n+1}$ then $k|S_{n+2}$.  Since the initial values of $S_n$ are $S_0=8$ and $S_1=368$, we can see inductively that $8|S_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$.

Comment: I was just writing this up then looked back and saw you had written the same thing. (+1)